# Blue Prism How to calculate text date times?

Tags: blueprism

is it possible to calculate text dates? Or to remove just the rest of my text?

I need to calculate days of leave. I have two data items and I must substract one from another. For example 11/3/2017 12:00:00 AM - 3/31/2017 12:00:00 AM. How can I do this? So far I've tried Replace function. I wanted to use Mid, Trim and Left but the characters in my date items are going to change. so sometimes I will have 9 characters (11/3/2017) and sometimes 8 (1/3/2017).

Which function could I use ?
this format is month/day/year and mine is day/month/year

Comment: Functionality to parse a date string that doesn't conform to the current locale's standard date formatting is not supported in Blue Prism out of the box. You'll need to extend the functionality offered in the bundled `Utility - Date and Time Manipulation` VBO and create an action and code stage to accomplish the reversal of the date format into one you can manipulate with Blue Prism's default functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Please see below how this could be achieved using the out of the box function available in Blue Prism Calculate Stage.

```
DateDiff(9, ToDate([Date1]), ToDate([Date2]))
```

DateDiff is an out of the box function which is used to find the difference in date.
`DateDiff (interval,date1,date2)`

Parameters
The three parameters are as follows:

- Interval - A code specifying the desired units of the return value.
- date1 - The first of the two dates for comparison.
- date2 - The second of the two dates for comparison.

#### Interval Definition

- 0 - Year
- 1 - Week of year (Calendar week)
- 2 - Weekday (Full 7 day week)
- 3 - Second
- 4 - Quarter
- 5 - Month
- 6 - Minute
- 7 - Hour
- 8 - Day of year
- 9 - Day

  `ToDate([Text})` This function is used to convert text to Date, provided the format matches.

Date1 - 3/31/2017 12:00:00 AM

Date2 - 11/3/2017 12:00:00 AM

DateDiff Result is 217 days as we are using interval 9 to find days. (Please see above the interval option for more options)